# asynchronous Twitter search

Tags: c#, search, stream, twitter

I am doing some research on twitter for college and am trying to create a simple twitter streaming app or search app in c# with asychronous capabilities i.e. I need to update the results on screen as new results are available.

Am I correct in saying that the streaming api returns much more detail than the search. Streaming returns detail such as the number of followers, friends, account creation date etc while the search returns very little? Can more detail be returned using the search method?
As I have alot of code written for both stream and search and have code that writes to the screen and DB i wont post anything yet, so i guess i am wondering has anyone any idea of the best way to approach to my predicament?!?

Any help at all is much appreciated and thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the streaming API returns the full tweet payload (including the embedded user object) as the tweets come off the endpoint, where the search API returns its unique flavor of result.  Personally, I listen to the [*statuses/filter*](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/filter) endpoint and backfill any missed tweets using the REST API.

Comment: Hi arcain, Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I have taken on bord your advise and since have found a goo link http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-tutorials/aggregating-tweets-search-api-vs-streaming-api/